# Why this fgets() behaving in a weird way?

Tags: c

I'm using strstr() function to search a string given by the user in some other string.

Problem is that when I use fgets() to take input, the strstr() function is giving zero(false) even if the string entered by user is there.

---

*For Example:*

```
char search[20];  //MAX size of search term is 20 bytes
puts("Enter search term: ");
fgets(search,20,stdin);  //suppose user enters: photographer (12 characters long)
if(strstr("I'm no photographer but I can picture us together",search))
    puts("Found!");
else
    puts("No luck!");
```

> Output: No luck!
>
> Even tough "photographer" is there in the string

---

However, if I use scanf() to take search input.

```
scanf("%19s",search); //like this
```

> Output: Found!

---

Why is this happening ?

Comment: A debugger would easily have shown the extra char issue.  Downvote.

Comment: I'm learning, I'm yet to learn that gdb thing. soon I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because `fgets()` stores a trailin newline `\n` at the end of the string read. So the string you read in `search` is basically `"photographer\n"`

---

Either use `scanf()` or overwrite a null character `\0` on the newline.

---

To overwrite on the newline, you can do something like this

```
l=strlen(search)-1;
if(search[l]=='\n')
    search[l]='\0';
```

Comment: Really helps man. Also, I tried to print out every single character in decimal(%d) formal in search string..and I got 10 at 13th place which is the ASCII value of \n..So, yeah.

Answer (score 1):

from the manual:

fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by  s. Reading stops  after  an  EOF  or  a  newline.  **If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffe**r.  A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in the buffer.

beware that none of those functions are safe to use because they don't check the size of the buffer.